# Ruby: relationship between two methods with same name, one is 'super' to the other

Tags: ruby

In the the following tea timer code, there's a 'start' method inside SleepTimer, which calls 'notify.'

```
  def start
    sleep minutes * 60
    notifier.notify("Tea is ready!")
  end
```

If you look at the code below, you'll see that there's a notify method in the `class StdioUi` as well as a notify method in `module UiWithBeep`. The start method shown above calls the notify method in `module UiWithBeep`, which then, via 'super,' calls the notify method in `class StdioUi`. (The effect is that "BEEP!" is heard before "Tea is ready".) However, I don't understand why notifier.notify calls the notify method in `module UiWithBeep` rather than in `class StdioUi`. 
**First Question:** how does it know to go to the one 'notify' over the other. 
**SecondQuestion** And, although I understand super, what establishes the relationship so that notify in `class StdioUi` is 'super' to the other notify. Can you please explain

Tea Timer

```
class TeaClock
  attr_accessor :timer
  attr_accessor :ui

  def initialize(minutes)

    self.ui = StdioUi.new

    self.timer = SleepTimer.new(minutes, ui)
    init_plugins

  end

  def init_plugins
    puts "init plugins"
    @plugins = []
    ::Plugins.constants.each do |name|
      @plugins << ::Plugins.const_get(name).new(self)
    end
  end

  def start
    timer.start
  end
end

class StdioUi
  def notify(text)
    puts text
  end
end

SleepTimer = Struct.new(:minutes, :notifier) do
  def start
    sleep minutes * 60
    notifier.notify("Tea is ready!")
  end
end

module Plugins
  class Beep    
    def initialize(tea_clock)

      tea_clock.ui.extend(UiWithBeep)
    end

    module UiWithBeep
      def notify(*)         #gets called by notifier.notify("Tea is ready")
        puts "BEEP!"

        super               #calls notify in class StdioUi
      end
    end
  end
end

t = TeaClock.new(0.01).start
```

Comment: RubyTapas episodes have comments now, so you could have posted this the episode :-) Looks like you found an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Book**: I keep recommending this excellent book, [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby). I was consulting it while composing this answer.

---

So, here you extend an object with a module. In Ruby it's called Object Extension. In simple cases it all works as expected, like this one:

```
module Foo
  def hello
    puts "foo"
  end
end

class Bar
end

bar = Bar.new
bar.extend Foo
bar.hello
# >> foo
```

Things get complicated when there are class' own methods involved. Here's a simplified version of your snippet that exhibits the same behaviour.

```
module Foo
  def hello
    puts "foo"
    super
  end
end

class Bar
  def hello
    puts 'bar'
  end
end

bar = Bar.new
bar.extend Foo
bar.hello
# >> foo
# >> bar
```

When you call a method in ruby, the interpreter has to first find a method to call. This is called Method Lookup. Now, when you define an instance method, in reality it's a method on class object, not that instance. So, method lookup goes like this for first snippet:

```
 1) bar instance => method hello not found here
 2) Bar class => method hello found
```

When you extend an object, however, methods are injected into instance's `eigenclass`. It's a special "hidden" class, unique for each instance. And in reality method lookup goes through it first. First snippet again:

```
 1) bar instance => method hello not found here
 2) bar's eigenclass => method hello not found here
 3) Bar class => method hello found
```

Now it should be clear why `Foo.hello` is called instead of `Bar.hello`: because it appears earlier in the method lookup process!

```
 1) bar instance => method hello not found here
 2) bar's eigenclass => method hello found
```

I may have made a few mistakes but this is roughly what happens.

Answer (score 1):

each class has a property called `ancestors` that represents the inheritance chain. ruby walks through the list of inherited behavior and looks for matching methods. if it finds one, it calls it with the given parameters. if you call `super` it looks for the next match.

```
1.9.3-p194 :003 > String.class.ancestors
 => [Class, Mocha::ClassMethods, Module, NewRelic::Agent::MethodTracer::InstanceMethods, NewRelic::Agent::MethodTracer::InstanceMethods::TraceExecutionScoped, NewRelic::Agent::MethodTracer::ClassMethods, NewRelic::Agent::MethodTracer::ClassMethods::AddMethodTracer, Mocha::ModuleMethods, ActiveSupport::Dependencies::ModuleConstMissing, Object, FactoryGirl::Syntax::Vintage, Metaclass::ObjectMethods, Mocha::ObjectMethods, PP::ObjectMixin, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable, FriendlyId::ObjectUtils, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn't StdioUi version be called first? Because it's defined there. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @sergioTulentsev it's defined there, and isn't StdioUi instance also passed in as the :notifier param to SleepTimer? that's what I don't get.

Comment: @user1647484: I know what's happening. Wait, I'm preparing a good snippet :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah, your right, it does not explain the functionality of ```extend```. ```eigenclass``` is a topic of it's own.